# Getting user process pid when writing Linux Kernel Module

Tags: c, linux, kernel-module

How can I get the PID of the user process which triggered my Kernel module's `file_operation.read` routine (i.e., which process is reading `/dev/mydev`) ?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

When your read function is executing, it's doing so in the context of the process that issued the system call. You should thus pe able to use `current`, i.e. `current->pid`.

Comment: what is current? read doesn't get a current as argument...
ssize_t(*read) (struct file *, char __user *, size_t, loff_t *);

Answer (score 17):

These days, we have some helper functions defined in sched.h.  In the case of pid, you can use:

```
pid = task_pid_nr(current);
```

to get the current task's pid.

here is the comment taken from [`include/linux/sched.h`](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/include/linux/sched.h?id=v3.8#n1683) as of v3.8.

> the helpers to get the task's different pids as they are seen
>   from various namespaces
>
> - task_xid_nr()     : global id, i.e. the id seen from the init namespace;
> - task_xid_vnr()    : virtual id, i.e. the id seen from the pid namespace of current.
> - task_xid_nr_ns()  : id seen from the ns specified;
> - set_task_vxid()   : assigns a virtual id to a task;
>
> see also pid_nr() etc in include/linux/pid.h

Answer (score 5):

On a kernel 2.6.39 arm build, if `current->pid` does not work then it may be done by:

```
    pid_nr(get_task_pid(current, PIDTYPE_PID))
```

The `PIDTYPE_PID` can be substituted by `PIDTYPE_PGID` or `PIDTYPE_SID`. The header source is at `include/linux/pid.h` as Yasushi pointed out.

Which of the approaches work depends on what header files the code uses.