# Linux character-device protection

Tags: char, kernel, linux-device-driver

I would like to protect my character device,from application operations.
I would like that only specific application can do operation on the device.

How can I do it?

Thanks

Comment: How would you identify that your application is accessing it?

Comment: This is what I am asking ...

Comment: Basic security in *nix employs file permissions and ownership.  Printer ports are owned by lpadmin to restrict access.  In a similar manner, allow **rw** access to the char device node only to the same unique username & group that owns the app.  But if you're looking for something that cannot be defeated, then you need to look for security dongles, i.e. a hardware solution.

Comment: I am writing the char device, can I just define a specific unique application name, and deny all the others ? When the app is open the device file I will query the process name, if there is no match I will return -ENODEV

Comment: You need to use SELinux. It is not possible to restrict access at the device level. No Linux device driver has any information about the application code that made the system call that performs a device operation.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be correct answer(Because I didn't test it). But I believe this will work.

I hope, you have idea about current field in `task_struct` which will give you the current PID of the process. Please refer this thread.  [how does current->pid work for linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10838342/how-does-current-pid-work-for-linux)

so instead of pid, you can use `comm` field of task_struct.

http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/sched.h#L1180.

Keep an array of allowed application names in your driver. check `comm` field against allowed list during `/dev/<yourchardriver>` open() operation.

**sample file operations structure.**

```
struct file_operations fops = { /* these are the file operations provided by our driver */
    .owner = THIS_MODULE, /*prevents unloading when operations are in use*/
    .open = device_open,  /*to open the device*/
    .write = device_write, /*to write to the device*/
    .read = device_read, /*to read the device*/
    .release = device_close, /*to close the device*/
    .llseek = device_lseek
};
```

when you call open("/dev/sampledrv") in user space, device_open() will be called in your driver. so these validation can be done here.

Comment: This answer is a candidate for downvote because it is not clear how the device driver could get the task struct.

Comment: @JonathanBen-Avraham by referring http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11915728/getting-user-process-pid-when-writing-linux-kernel-module and few more threads, I just assumed. May be I will test and let you know.

Comment: I think that this might work, but you need to add a snippet of code that gives an idea of how. Use an example UART driver, or trivial `misc` example driver's `open` function to show where and how you would add the proposed code.